# How can I make the user always logged in? React Native

Tags: react-native, firebase-authentication

Using the code below, how do I get the user to be logged in every time the user opens the application?

```
export default class LoginScreen extends Component {

constructor() {
  super();
  this.state = { 
    email: '', 
    password: '',
  }
}

updateInputVal = (val, prop) => {
  const state = this.state;
  state[prop] = val;
  this.setState(state);
}

userLogin = () => {
  if(this.state.email === '' && this.state.password === '') {
    Alert.alert('Enter details to signin!')
  } else {
    
    firebase
    .auth()
    .signInWithEmailAndPassword(this.state.email, this.state.password)
    .then((res) => {
      console.log(res)
      console.log('User logged-in successfully!')
      Alert.alert('Succesfully logged')
      this.setState({
        email: '', 
        password: ''
      })
      this.props.navigation.navigate('Home')
    })
    
    .catch(error => this.setState({ errorMessage: Alert.alert('Not logged') }))
     
  }
}
```

I'm trying to make a fashion application that includes a profile.

After that, I'm going to put the sign-out but it's already quite clear to me how to do it.

Thanks!!

Comment: I haven't used Firebase Auth for a while, but maybe this documentation might help you. https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/auth-state-persistence#supported_types_of_auth_state_persistence

Answer (score 0, accepted):

firebase authentication keeps user signed in

check for login information in `componentDidMount` using

```
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user)=>{

})
```

if user exists navigate to home screen